# weatherian app is not working in 23.10

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, 23.10, weather

Weatherian app is not working in 23.10, the app just doesnt open. the app seems to start open, the icon on the bar appears then disapears. i am just reporting this so that this will be fix, so that people are also able to use it. And dont know if this is a good app.

Also what is the best weather app on ubuntu?
Besides weatherian i have weather, gnome by robert ancell but for my location is no data,no information avaiable, and the app doesnt appear on the top menu like in ubuntu 23.04.

even with the recent updates the app doesnt work, and the other still doesnt show my location